# Why won't my ArrayList sort with a comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Here is my code

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Emily");
    list.add("Gary");
    list.add("Harry");
    list.add("Tom");

    Comparator<String> name;
    name = (String e1, String e2) -> e2.compareTo(e1);

    Collections.sort(list, name);

    for(String user: list){
        System.out.println(user);
    }
```

I want to sort the names in list alphabetically using a comparator but when I print the sorted list out it isn't sorted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run your code, it is sorted.  Using your Comparator.  What makes you think it isn't sorted?

Comment: Also, for types like `String` that have a natural ordering, you don't need to write you own comparator, you can get the same effect by just using `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reversing places of `e2` and `e1`, so your output is reverse (from Z to A), if you want to sort alphabetically (from A to Z) you would do:

```
e1.compareTo(e2);
```

but since String class is Comparable, you don't have to make your own Comparator to sort it alphabetically, you can just call sort and it will be sorted in alphabetical (natural order for Strings) order.

So you can just do:

```
Collections.sort(yourListHere);
```